# error in Rechability.m

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

i am getting the following error as shown in below image
[image]

I removed this file and again added the new one even though same error occurs

i am unable to find where to modify?

Please Guide Me

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You're missing a parenthesis somewhere above the interface line in the code, that's what is causing the errors.

Comment: Is the file really called Reachability.m?

Comment: i am not missing any parenthesis @CBredlow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably compiling this file as Objective-C++, not Objective-C. You can usually tell from the file extension, which is probably ".mm" (or this is a header file which you include from ObjC++ somewhere).

`private` is a reserved word in C++ (and ObjC++). A quick fix would be to spell `Private` with a capital `P` instead.